# PoE Transformer

Tags: poe

I am using a transformer (7490220122) for signal isolation on a PoE controller design. If I am using 2 pair of the ethernet cable for data and 4 pair to provide the necessary power to the PoE device. Do I need to do anything with the 2 spare data pair coming out of the transformer or can I leave the pins open? In the design I don't plan on using TD3, TD4 pairs for their data, can I just leave the connections open instead of connecting to J2? Or do they require termination? If yes, what kind of termination?

[image]

Comment: "I am using 2 pair of the ethernet cable for data and 4 pair to provide the necessary power to the PoE device" Not following: PoE is all about using the same conductors for data and power. Are you really doing PoE?

Comment: You are correct, but you don't need to use all 4 Pair for data. Tx and Rx run on two of the 4 pair...so the other two can be spare pair when it comes to data.